# Porting from django-social-auth to python-social-auth: AuthCanceled exception

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I created a social login on my project using django-social-auth. While porting to python-social-auth using instructions found on the documentation (http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/configuration/porting_from_dsa.html) I've ran into a problem while logging on Facebook:

```
AuthCanceled at /en/complete/facebook/
Authentication process canceled
```

Traceback:

```
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  394.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/utils.py" in wrapper
  51.             return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/views.py" in complete
  28.                        redirect_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/actions.py" in do_complete
  43.         user = backend.complete(user=user, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/base.py" in complete
  41.         return self.auth_complete(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/utils.py" in wrapper
  232.                 raise AuthCanceled(args[0])
```

I've also changed my Porting settings correctly, but here they are nevertheless.

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = 'app_id'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_API_SECRET = 'secret'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email', 'publish_actions']

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_UID_LENGTH = 223
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_NONCE_SERVER_URL_LENGTH = 200
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_ASSOCIATION_SERVER_URL_LENGTH = 200
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_ASSOCIATION_HANDLE_LENGTH = 200

SOCIAL_AUTH_USERNAME_IS_FULL_EMAIL = True

SOCIAL_AUTH_DISCONNECT_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.disconnect.get_entries',
    'social.pipeline.disconnect.revoke_tokens',
    'social.pipeline.disconnect.disconnect'
)

SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"

SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_RAISE_EXCEPTIONS = False
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the docs for the exception middleware here http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/configuration/django.html#exceptions-middleware

Comment: Yes, that how I deal with the thrown exception. My question is how can I solve this given error. Even reproducing almost exactly the steps to port from django-social-auth, as soon as I click sign in it gives me "Authentication process canceled"